# How to show that these integrals are left unchanged by this substitution?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, integration

I am looking at the solutions of a physics homework, and these solutions assume that the following quantities:
\begin{equation}
\int\text{d}^Dx\frac{\phi^n(x)}{n!}
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
\int\text{d}^Dx\frac{\left(\nabla\phi(x)\right)^2}{n!}
\end{equation}
are left unchanged by the substitution
\begin{equation}
\phi(x) \to \phi(Rx)
\end{equation}
where $R$ is a constant matrix and $RR^T = R^TR = I$.

I don't know why is this true. For example for the first quantity:

Let $u = Rx$, then $\text{d}^Dx = R^T\text{d}^Du$ and the expression becomes:
\begin{equation}
\left(R^T\right)^D\int\text{d}^Du\frac{\phi^n(u)}{n!}
\end{equation}

I am confused how to show that both quantities are left unchanged.

Comment: "$u=Rx$ then $d^Dx=R^Td^Du$".... um NO. This is why you shouldn't just work symbolically with the differentials. You should understand what the notation means and what it doesn't. Here the relevant result is the change of variables theorem from multivariable calculus; the Jacobian determinant here is $\det R=1$, and the image under $R$ of $\Bbb{R}^D$ is still $\Bbb{R}^D$ (i.e $R(\Bbb{R}^D)=\Bbb{R}^D$) which is why the integrals remain unchanged.

Comment: @peek-a-boo Could you turn your comment into an answer. It was very helpful to understanding where I was wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just repeating my comment to get this answered. "$u=Rx$ then $d^Dx=R^Td^Du$".... NO. This is why you shouldn't just work symbolically with the differentials. You should understand what the notation means and what it doesn't. Here the relevant result is the change of variables theorem from multivariable calculus (under certain hypotheses, $\int_{g(A)}f=\int_A(f\circ g)\cdot |\det Dg|$); the Jacobian determinant here is $\det R=1$ (we're also using the fact here that $R$ is a matrix, so it induces a linear transformation, which we still denote $R$, in a natural way, and at every point $p$, we have $DR_p=R$, so $\det DR = 1$ identically), and the image under $R$ of $\Bbb{R}^D$ is still $\Bbb{R}^D$ (i.e $R(\Bbb{R}^D)=\Bbb{R}^D$) which is why the integrals remain unchanged.

Comment: Is there anything special about the2 quantities in my question? Do they fit in the "under certain hypothesis"? Or will any integral remain unchanged under a transformation of a constant matrix as above?

Comment: @user17004502 The full theorem (granted there are slightly more general versions) is "Let $U,V\subset\Bbb{R}^n$ be open set, $g:U\to V$ a $C^1$, and $f:V\to \Bbb{C}$ Lebesgue integrable. Then, for any measurable set $A\subset U$, we have $\int_{g(A)}f= \int_A(f\circ g)\cdot |\det Dg|$". In your case, the sets involved are $U=V=A=\Bbb{R}^n$, and the mapping $g$ is $g(x):= R\cdot x$, left-multiplication of a column vector by an invertible matrix, and $f$ here is your $\phi$.

Comment: So as long as your function $\phi$ is nice enough (say $C^1$ because you're also talking about $\nabla\phi$) and decays quick enough, yes all the hypotheses are satisfied, so the theorem can safely be applied. In your case, you're considering orthogonal matrices, so they have determinant $1$ (and also invertible matrices map $\Bbb{R}^n$ onto $\Bbb{R}^n$), and this is crucial to why the integral remains the same. If you had a different constant matrix, say $2I$ (twice the identity), then the determinant would be $\det(2I)=2^n$, so the integral is no longer the same (there's an extra factor).

Comment: But this should be familiar even from 1-dimensional calculus: $\int_{\Bbb{R}}f(x)\,dx=\int_{\Bbb{R}}f(2t)\cdot 2\,dt$; here the $n$ is $1$, so $2^1$ is the multiplicative factor. In general for arbitrary invertible matrices, you multiply by the determinant (and determinants appear because they encode how volumes of subsets change).

Comment: oops my first comment should say "$g:U\to V$ a $C^1$ **diffeomorphism**". Left out the most important part of the hypothesis.